# Source control wiped project

Tags: xcode

I had a project I'd been working on and I wanted to start a new branch so that I could make edits without ruining the original

I went to source control, new branch.. etc. I ended up discarding all changes in the new branch but when I returned to the master branch, everything was gone. My files are still in the folder in finder but they arent showing up in xcode. My storyboard files when opened separately are blank.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If your changes are saved in remote repository, then you can pull all your changes for that branch from remote repository.

on master branch run this command

```
 git pull origin master
```

Comment: Not saved on a remote server- - do you know what happened

Comment: check the status of your repository.What is the status?

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: If you are using git for version control then in console , run command git status

Comment: Okay, what am i looking for

Comment: All my podfiles still show up. Is my stuff gone, or is xcode not finding it or something?

Comment: Do you have all your files listed in master branch, when you run git status command? Is there any changes listed when you run the git status command?

Comment: Alot of the files are in red. But missing ViewController, App delegate, storyboard..info.plist... things that come with the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142677/discussion-between-jitendra-solanki-and-huddie96).